# Zeros of real analytic functions

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, reference-request, roots

It is known that given a discrete set of points on the complex plane with prescribed multiplicities, there exists a complex holomorphic function with zeros at those points with the prescribed multiplicities. Does a corresponding result hold true for real analytic functions of a single variable if a discrete set of points with prescribed multiplicities are given on the real line?

Comment: A real-analytic function of a single real variable, I presume. A real-analytic function is the restriction of a holomorphic function to (the intersection of the domain and) the real line.

Comment: @DanielFischer I see, so just take the holomorphic function with those real zeros, take the Taylor series expansion of the holomorphic function, and substitute the complex variable $z$ with the real variable $x$, right?

Comment: Yes. Although if you want real-valued functions, there is a small point to be considered. If you have two zeros $z_1,z_2$ with multiplicities $n_1,n_2$ prescribed, it may happen that for the constructed holomorphic solution $f$ you have e.g. $f^{(n_1)}(z_1) \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f^{(n_2)}(z_2) \in i\mathbb{R}$, and then the real as well as the imaginary part of $f$ would have a zero of too high order at one of the points. You can avoid that, but one must be aware of the possibility.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, that is indeed a point. However, if I am just replacing the complex variable $z$ with the real variable $x$, I am avoiding that issue altogether, right? Basically, if $f(z) = (z - z_1)^{n_1}(z - z_2)^{n_2}\varphi (z)$, where $z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{R}$, and $\varphi (z_1) \neq 0$ and $\varphi (z_2) \neq 0$, then $g(x) = (x  - z_1)^{n_1}(x - z_2)^{n_2}\varphi (x)$ should be real-valued real analytic, right?

Comment: If you just replace the complex variable with a real variable, you may get a complex-valued function, but that is guaranteed to have the right orders of the zeros. However, the standard constructions to obtain a holomorphic function with prescribed zeros yield functions that are real-valued on $\mathbb{R}$ if all prescribed zeros are real (or even when the prescribed zeros are symmetric with respect to the real axis). So the caveat is mostly a theoretical one.